# gsoap calc++ example ended up with error

Tags: gsoap

I am trying to build calc++ after looking into tutorial given here https://www.genivia.com/examples/calc++/index.html but end up with error as shown below.

Here are the steps i followed

1. wsdl2h -o calc.h http://www.genivia.com/calc.wsdl [This created the
   header file and i am not sure what to do file "typemap.dat" file so
   i proceed with second step]
2. soapcpp2 -j -r -CL calc.h [This generates the required files and i downloaded the calcclient.cpp , copied the stdsoap2.h and stdsoap2.cpp in the same folder]
3. g++ -o calcclient calcclient.cpp stdsoap2.cpp soapC.cpp soapcalcProxy.cpp [This step ends with the error shown below]

Can anybody help me regarding this, i am totally new to gsoap and trying to build something with it so i decided to start with gsoap example but getting this big error. I am doing this in Ubuntu and following the exact steps which is given in the tutorial.Please check error below

```
calcclient.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
calcclient.cpp:58:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘calcProxy::add(double&, double&, double*)’
   calc.add(a, b, &result);
                         ^
In file included from calcclient.cpp:41:0:
soapcalcProxy.h:74:21: note: candidate: virtual int calcProxy::add(double, double, double&)
     virtual int add(double a, double b, double &result)
                 ^
soapcalcProxy.h:74:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘double*’ to ‘double&’
soapcalcProxy.h:76:21: note: candidate: virtual int calcProxy::add(const char*, const char*, double, double, double&)
     virtual int add(const char *soap_endpoint, const char *soap_action, double a, double b, double &result);
                 ^
soapcalcProxy.h:76:21: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 3 provided
calcclient.cpp:61:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘calcProxy::sub(double&, double&, double*)’
   calc.sub(a, b, &result);
                         ^
In file included from calcclient.cpp:41:0:
soapcalcProxy.h:78:21: note: candidate: virtual int calcProxy::sub(double, double, double&)
     virtual int sub(double a, double b, double &result)
                 ^
soapcalcProxy.h:78:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘double*’ to ‘double&’
soapcalcProxy.h:80:21: note: candidate: virtual int calcProxy::sub(const char*, const char*, double, double, double&)
     virtual int sub(const char *soap_endpoint, const char *soap_action, double a, double b, double &result);
                 ^
soapcalcProxy.h:80:21: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 3 provided
calcclient.cpp:64:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘calcProxy::mul(double&, double&, double*)’
   calc.mul(a, b, &result);
                         ^
In file included from calcclient.cpp:41:0:
soapcalcProxy.h:82:21: note: candidate: virtual int calcProxy::mul(double, double, double&)
     virtual int mul(double a, double b, double &result)
                 ^
soapcalcProxy.h:82:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘double*’ to ‘double&’
soapcalcProxy.h:84:21: note: candidate: virtual int calcProxy::mul(const char*, const char*, double, double, double&)
     virtual int mul(const char *soap_endpoint, const char *soap_action, double a, double b, double &result);
                 ^
soapcalcProxy.h:84:21: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 3 provided
calcclient.cpp:67:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘calcProxy::div(double&, double&, double*)’
   calc.div(a, b, &result);
                         ^
In file included from calcclient.cpp:41:0:
soapcalcProxy.h:86:21: note: candidate: virtual int calcProxy::div(double, double, double&)
     virtual int div(double a, double b, double &result)
                 ^
soapcalcProxy.h:86:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘double*’ to ‘double&’
soapcalcProxy.h:88:21: note: candidate: virtual int calcProxy::div(const char*, const char*, double, double, double&)
     virtual int div(const char *soap_endpoint, const char *soap_action, double a, double b, double &result);
                 ^
soapcalcProxy.h:88:21: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 3 provided
calcclient.cpp:70:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘calcProxy::pow(double&, double&, double*)’
   calc.pow(a, b, &result);
                         ^
In file included from calcclient.cpp:41:0:
soapcalcProxy.h:90:21: note: candidate: virtual int calcProxy::pow(double, double, double&)
     virtual int pow(double a, double b, double &result)
                 ^
soapcalcProxy.h:90:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘double*’ to ‘double&’
soapcalcProxy.h:92:21: note: candidate: virtual int calcProxy::pow(const char*, const char*, double, double, double&)
     virtual int pow(const char *soap_endpoint, const char *soap_action, double a, double b, double &result);
                 ^
soapcalcProxy.h:92:21: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 3 provided
```

Comment: Never have knowledge about gsoap but is it possible that you missed to include a required file?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are passing one or more arguments as a pointer. The correct proxy call should look like this:

```
#include "soapcalcProxy.h"
#include "calc.nsmap"

  double a, b, result;
  calcProxy calc("http://server.com/path");
  a = 1.23;
  b = 4.56;
  int err = calc.add(a, b, result);
```

Comment: Can you please check the link in first line, see that example and let me know about the changes as i didn't change anything in the example. I just downloaded the "calcclient.cpp" and followed the instruction which is given in tutorial.

Comment: Can anybody answer about this !!

Comment: I think there may be a typo in the example, the `result` should be passed by reference, not by pointer, after running wsdl2h and soapcpp2 tools to generate the code. I'm getting a reference. Replacing `&result` argument with `result` works.

Comment: I've suggested to them to update the example which is now available here: https://www.genivia.com/examples/calc++/index.html